# NSObject unable to convert

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting errors on the following lines of code.
Since this is a project I just downloaded from github,https://github.com/HubSpot/BidHub-iOS
I am not sure what these lines are doing.

```
  let one = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "BID\n", attributes: bidAttrs as [NSObject : AnyObject] as [NSObject : AnyObject] )
    one.appendAttributedString(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "$\(startAmount + incrementOne)", attributes: otherAttrs))
    plusOneButton.setAttributedTitle(one, forState: .Normal)

    let five = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "BID\n", attributes: bidAttrs as [NSObject : AnyObject] as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    five.appendAttributedString(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "$\(startAmount + incrementFive)", attributes: otherAttrs))
    plusFiveButton.setAttributedTitle(five, forState: .Normal)

    let ten = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "BID\n", attributes: bidAttrs as [NSObject : AnyObject] as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    ten.appendAttributedString(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "$\(startAmount + incrementTen)", attributes: otherAttrs))
    plusTenButton.setAttributedTitle(ten, forState: .Normal)
```

Error is as follows

```
/Users/David/Desktop/iOS_app/Bid-Hub-app/iOS-app/BidHub-iOS-master/AuctionApp/BiddingVC/BiddingViewController.swift:104:109: Cannot convert value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]?'
/Users/DAVID/Desktop/iOS_app/Bid-Hub-app/iOS-app/BidHub-iOS-master/AuctionApp/BiddingVC/BiddingViewController.swift:112:109: Cannot convert value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]?'
/Users/DAVID/Desktop/iOS_app/Bid-Hub-app/iOS-app/BidHub-iOS-master/AuctionApp/BiddingVC/BiddingViewController.swift:108:110: Cannot convert value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]?'
```

So just before you suggest me to remove the extra

```
as [NSObject : AnyObject]
```

Already tried that, and it gives the following error

```
/Users/David/Desktop/iOS_app/Bid-Hub-app/iOS-app/BidHub-iOS-master/AuctionApp/BiddingVC/BiddingViewController.swift:104:74: 'NSDictionary' is not implicitly convertible to '[NSObject : AnyObject]'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?
```

EDIT:

```
var bidAttrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 14.0)! , NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor()] as NSDictionary
```

Comment: you are passing `bidAttrs` and casting it to `[NSObject : AnyObject]`, while the initializer expects it to be of type `[String : AnyObject]?`

Comment: @konrad.bajtyngier so what exactly do I have to change?

Comment: what does `bidAttrs` consist of? but you should be able to skip casting all together

Comment: @konrad.bajtyngier check my edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to cast `bidAttrs` to `NSDictionary`, so simply do this:

```
var bidAttrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 14.0)! , NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor()]
let one = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "BID\n", attributes: bidAttrs )
```

However, if you need it to be an `NSDictionary` for some reason, your casting should look like this:

```
let one = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "BID\n", attributes: bidAttrs as? [String : AnyObject] )
```

Comment: have another but similar issue, but the same solution doesn't work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063265/nsobject-unable-to-convert-string