# NSObject unable to convert string

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code but I am getting error at wrong conversion, still learning what exactly the below code is trying to do, so not sure what the code means yet.

```
 let padding = 353
 let minHeightText: NSString = "\n\n"
 let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Light", size: 15.0)!
 let attributes =  [NSFontAttributeName: font] as NSDictionary
 let item = items[indexPath.row]
 let minSize = minHeightText.boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: (view.frame.size.width - 40), height: 1000), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes as [NSObject : AnyObject] as [NSObject : AnyObject], context: nil).height
 let maxSize = item.itemDesctiption.boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: (view.frame.size.width - 40), height: 1000), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes as [NSObject : AnyObject] as [NSObject : AnyObject], context: nil).height + 50
```

The error I am getting is this..

```
/Users/David/Desktop/iOS_app/Bid-Hub-app/iOS-app/BidHub-iOS-master/AuctionApp/ItemList/ItemListViewController.swift:140:215: Cannot convert value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]?'
/Users/David/Desktop/iOS_app/Bid-Hub-app/iOS-app/BidHub-iOS-master/AuctionApp/ItemList/ItemListViewController.swift:138:208: Cannot convert value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]?'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for casting `attributes` to `NSDictionary`. Make the following changes:

```
let attributes =  [NSFontAttributeName: font] as NSDictionary
```

should be

```
let attributes =  [NSFontAttributeName: font]
```

and remove casting to `[NSObject : AnyObject]`